# SEDA concurrent consumer and processing time

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

For the following code: fileLineToObject bean converts a line to object and send each object to a direct:member endpoint in a loop for all line in a file using Producer Template.

```
<template id="MemberTemplate" defaultEndpoint="direct:member" />

<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <bean ref="fileLineToObject"/>
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:member"
    ......
    <to uri="seda:input">
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="seda:input?concurrentConsumers=4" />
    <bean ref="abcProcessor" /> // These are complete CPU bound. 
    <bean ref="xyzProcessor" />
    <to uri="direct:xxx" />
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:xxx"
    ......
    <to uri="seda:output">
</route>
<route>
    <from uri="seda:output?concurrentConsumers=4"
    ......
    <to uri="file:xxx">
</route>
```

There is NO difference is processing time(negligible) regardless of the number of seda input or output concurrent consumer. I am testing on quad core PC. Is it because of the limited core?

How can I decrease processing time using concurrency?

Comment: On first glance it looks to me like you should get parallel processing of the lines. You can check whether multiple threads are at work for you by configuring the logging framework of your choice to include the thread name in the log pattern. Then print a log statement from the `seda:input` route to check if more than one thread is at work. And whether it is different from the thread running the `direct:start` route. Whether your CPU is maxed out should be obvious from the output of the CPU monitor of your system.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was looking at logs after I posted this and after looking at logs and CPU usage(all 4 cores start very high and stay at mid), I think that thread is working properly. 
One question if you don't mind: 
If I can see 4 threads operating at an instance of time then does it mean that I am utilizing threads in my application properly for 4 core pc?

Comment: In theory this results in the best workload distribution. Assuming your tasks are fully CPU bound and the 4 threads actually do get spread over the 4 cores and there is virtually no other activity on your system. If you cannot max out your cores, then your overall problem/application is not fully CPU bound.